# Elasticsearch query for simple category search, sorting by price and getting records by range

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I want to write query with following condition :

- search by category (like category = 'cat1')
- and with price range (and price between 100 to 500)
- and sort by price (low to high)

I tried:

```
    $params = [
                'index' => 'my_index',
                'type' => 'product',
                'body' =>  [
                        //"from" => 0, "size" => 2,
                        "sort" => [
                                    ["default_product_low_price.sale_price" => ["order" => "asc"]]
                                ],
                        'query'=> $query,
                        "aggs" => [
                        "default_product_low_price" => [
                        "nested" => [
                            "path" => "default_product_low_price"
                            ],
                        "aggs" => [
                                "range" => ["default_product_low_price.sale_price" => [ "gte" => '790',
                                "lte" => '1000' ]],
                                //"max_price" => ["max" => [ "field" => "default_product_low_price.sale_price" ]]
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
```

But I am getting an error

> Bad Request 400 Exception in GuzzleConnection.php line 277: error.

Please guide me where I am wrong? What is the right query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be your query :

```
      $params = [
                'index' => 'my_index',
                'type' => 'product',
                'body' =>  [
                    "sort" =>[
                                ["default_product_low_price.sale_price" => ["order" => "asc"]]
                            ],
                        "query"=> [
                          "filtered"=> [
                             "query"=> [
                                "match_all"=> []
                             ],
                             "query"=>[
                                       "term"=> [
                                          "category.name"=> "jeans"
                                       ]
                                    ],
                             "filter"=> [
                                "nested"=> [
                                   "path"=> "default_product_low_price",
                                   "filter"=> [
                                      "bool"=> [
                                         "must"=> [
                                            [
                                               "range"=> [
                                                  "default_product_low_price.sale_price"=> [
                                                    "gte"=> 100,
                                                    "lte"=> 200,
                                                  ]
                                               ]
                                            ]
                                         ]
                                      ]
                                   ]
                                ]
                             ]
                          ]
                       ]
                ]
            ];
```

Comment: Thanks bro... its perfect